# Как вызвать события для программно созданного компонента? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Ситуация такая. Например у меня есть список типа PictureBox. И, например, по нажатию на кнопку будет создаваться новый элемент списка. Выглядит это так:

`list.Add(new PictureBox());`

А как мне вызывать события для созданного PictureBox'a? Например, событие MouseHover. Как мне написать это событие?

Comment: так вы хотите вызвать событие или подписаться на событие?

Comment: `var pb = new PictureBox(); pb.MouseHover += ...; list.Add(pb);`

Comment: tym32167, хочу подписаться.